# UITableViewCell - can't get UIButton subview to overlap (and be tappable in) next cell in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9, subview

I am trying to add a UIButton subview to a UITableViewCell and have it overlap onto the cell below. Specifically, I want my implementation to look like the Edit Contact view in iOS Contacts, with the Contact photo (button) to the left and the first and last name to the right.

This used to work in iOS 7, and I am pretty certain it also worked in iOS 8. I have tried literally everything I can think of to get this to work in iOS 9. I can get the button to overlap into the next cell, but it is not tappable. No matter what, when I click on the bottom half of the button (the half that is in the overlap part of the second cell), the button is not recognized (nothing happens). Here are all of the things that I have tried, unsuccessfully.

When I created the tableView I set

```
tableView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

And

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case CONTACT_EDIT_SECTION: {
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case NAME_FIRST_ROW: case NAME_LAST_ROW:
                    [cell setClipsToBounds:NO];
                    [cell.contentView setClipsToBounds:NO];
                    [cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];
                    [cell.contentView.superview.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

I read that when a tableView is in editing mode, the cells get set back to cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES. So

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing {

    [super setEditing:editing];
    UITableView *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NAME_FIRST_ROW inSection:CONTACT_EDIT_SECTION]];
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;

    UITableView *cell2 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NAME_LAST_ROW inSection:CONTACT_EDIT_SECTION]];
    cell2.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;
}
```

Obviously, I tried setting clipsToBounds No in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case CONTACT_EDIT_SECTION: {
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case NAME_FIRST_ROW: case NAME_LAST_ROW: {
                    UITableViewCell *cell;
                    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                        cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Value1Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                        UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_CELL_MARGIN, (2*DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT-IMAGE_DIAMETER)/2.0, IMAGE_DIAMETER, IMAGE_DIAMETER)];
                        [imageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                        //[imageButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                        [imageButton.layer setCornerRadius:IMAGE_DIAMETER/2.0];
                        [imageButton.layer setBorderWidth:1];
                        [imageButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:200 green:200 blue:200 alpha:1].CGColor];
                        [imageButton setImage:_person.thumbnailImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(photoActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                        [cell.contentView.superview addSubview:imageButton];

                        [cell setClipsToBounds:NO];
                        [cell.contentView setClipsToBounds:NO];
                        [cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];
                        [cell.contentView.superview.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];

                    }
                    else {
                        cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Value1Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

                        [cell setClipsToBounds:NO];
                        [cell.contentView setClipsToBounds:NO];
                        [cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];
                        [cell.contentView.superview.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];
                    }
                    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
                    return cell;
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Usually after googling for four hours and trying everything I can possibly find, I can solve a problem like this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a cell with the multiple text fields and the portrait image in it. Overlapping from an external cell is very tetchy as the view order can be altered by the user scrolling cells in and out.

You can confirm this in the contacts app, when you select a phone number cell or anything below, it will highlight the cell, however when tapping the first/last/company cells, it doesn't do the highlight. This is because that is once cell in itself.

Comment: I know I can do this. I just wanted to avoid it. So, is what I described above just technically impossible then?

Comment: Even if you manage to get it to 'work' in iOS 9, there's no guarantee it won't break down the road in -say- iOS 10 (iOS X?). Better steer clear from quick-and-dirty hacks and implement a design that is semantic in terms of the intended use of the UIKit classes. It will pay off as less headaches.

Comment: Ok. That answers the question then. Thank you.